# Android: Adding images to the compose body of the email

Tags: android, email

Is there any way of adding images to the body of the mail (i.e Compose). I have some text with images that I want to dump into the compose of the mail. I don't need to add image has an attachment. I guess the Compose is an EditText. I wonder is it possible to add images to it??

Cheers,
Vinayak

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gmail interface doesn't support inline images as attachments.  If you absolutely need images inline, you'd have to upload them somewhere and include a link in your message.  Although, in the compose window I'm fairly certain you'd only be able to see the html.